# how to skip file from current upload queue at run time with blueimp fileupload

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, blueimp

Hi i have problem in skipping file from current upload queue.

my current scenario

1. i want to abort 2nd file when it starts uploading , so that it is not sent after `abort`
2. i want to skip 3rd file from upload queue - it is not a abort because current file only we can abort

here is how i'm doing it

```
    var uploadFileList = [];

   add: function (e, data) {
             uploadFileList.push(data.files[0].name);
             data.submit();
     },
    
    .on('fileuploadchunksend', function (e, data) {
            /** Abort code starts here **/
            var filename = uploadFileList[1]; //abort 2nd file
            var currentFilename = data.files[0].name;
            if(currentFilename == filename){
                  data.abort();
             }
            /** Abort code Ends here **/

            //skip code
             data.originalFiles.splice(3,1);
        })
```

**Note**:  i don't want any ui for `abort` or skip

here is full code (not skipping): http://jsfiddle.net/eabangalore/dm9j5uzn/84/

For current upload it will be abort and for queue it will be skip.

Please help me thanks in advance!!

Comment: @EaBengaluru what do you want to achieve exactly? You can remove or not submit files in the `add` callback.

Comment: @DipenShah i want to abort any current file from uploading, let say file 2

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

```js
$(function() {
  var skip = [2]; //file indexes to skip
  var abort = [1]; //file indexes to abort
  var uploadFileList = [];
  var indexAdd = 0;
  var countSubmit = 0;
  var countAlways = 0;
  var indexUpload = null;

  $('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: '/echo/json/',
    maxChunkSize: 1024 * 1024,
    maxRetries: 3,
    dataType: 'json',
    multipart: false,
    sequentialUploads: true,
    progress: function(e, data) {
      var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10),
        meter = $('.progress .meter'),
        percent = progress + '%';
      meter.css('width', percent).text(percent);
      $('#currentFileName').text(data.files[0].name);
    },
    add: function(e, data) {
      uploadFileList.push({ name: data.files[0].name, state: null, jqXHR: null });

      //Skip files in the skip array - i.e. don't start the file upload
      if (skip.indexOf(indexAdd)  !== -1) {
        $('#skipFilename').text(uploadFileList[indexAdd].name);
        uploadFileList[indexAdd].state = 'skipped';
        console.log(uploadFileList[indexAdd].name, 'skip');
      } else {
        uploadFileList[indexAdd].jqXHR = data.submit();
        countSubmit++;
      };

      indexAdd++;
    },
    done: function(e, data) {
      /* data.context.text('Upload finished.') */
      ;
    },
    fail: function(e, data) {}
  }).on('fileuploadchunksend', function(e, data) {
    /* $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
      console.log('fileuploadchunksend file: ' + file.name);
    }); */
    /** Abort code starts here **/
    /* var filename = uploadFileList[1]; //abort 2nd file
    var currentFilename = data.files[0].name;
    if (currentFilename == filename) {
      data.abort();
    } */
    /** Abort code Ends here **/
    console.log(data.files[0].name, 'fileuploadchunksend');
    
    //abort files in the abort array
     for(var i = 0; i < uploadFileList.length; i++) {
      if(uploadFileList[i].name === data.files[0].name) {
        indexUpload = i;
        
        if(abort.indexOf(i) !== -1) {
          setTimeout(abortUpload, 0); //setTimeout seems to solve the issue of the jqXHR.abort() not stopping the upload
        } else {
          uploadFileList[i].state = 'sent';
        };
      };
    };

    //skip code
    data.originalFiles.splice(3, 1);
  }).on('fileuploadchunkdone', function(e, data) {
   /*  console.info('testing', data); */
  }).on('fileuploadstop', function(e) {
    uploadFileList.length = 0;
    }).on('fileuploadsend', function (e, data) {
    console.log(data.files[0].name, 'send');    
    }).on('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
    console.log(data.files[0].name, 'done', getStatus(data));
  }).on('fileuploadfail', function (e, data) {
    console.log(data.files[0].name, 'fail', getStatus(data));
  }).on('fileuploadalways', function (e, data) {
    console.log(data.files[0].name, 'always', getStatus(data));
    countAlways++;
    
    if(countAlways === countSubmit) {
        for(var i = 0; i < uploadFileList.length; i++) {
        delete uploadFileList[i].jqXHR;
      };
        console.log('done', uploadFileList);
    };
  });
  
  function getStatus(data) {
    //check if aborted
    for(var i = 0; i < uploadFileList.length; i++) {
      if(uploadFileList[i].name === data.files[0].name && uploadFileList[i].state === 'aborted') {
        return 'abort';
      };
    };
    
    return data.textStatus;
  };
  
  function abortUpload() {
    if(uploadFileList[indexUpload].jqXHR !== null) {
      console.log(uploadFileList[indexUpload].name, 'aborting');
      uploadFileList[indexUpload].state = 'aborted';
      uploadFileList[indexUpload].jqXHR.abort();
    };
  };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0qmLw8pg/

Arrays of which files to skip or abort are initially set.

To skip a file (i.e. don't initiate upload), do not run `data.submit()` in the `add` callback for that file.

Abort works with [jQuery Ajax request](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API#how-to-cancel-an-upload) objects, e.g. returned from the `send` callback. `send` cannot be used in this case because it sends all the files, so you would not be able to skip any. It is possible to call a function which runs `abort` for a separate Ajax object returned for each file in the `add` callback. Another way to abort is to `return false` in the `fileuploadsend` [callback](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#callback-options) (just like jQuery Ajax [beforeSend](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)).

Logs to the console have been included so you can see it working. This code works assuming the file names are unique.

EDIT: Updated to work with Ajax objects and abort upload at any point after initial `fileuploadsend` e.g. (`fileuploadchunksend`).

Comment: your code works perfectly, but other than `fileuploadsend`  can we shift abort code so that i can get backend status and messages.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean by that. Can you elaborate, or give an example?

Comment: from backend i will get error status code inside `data.result.error_msg` as shown here https://ibb.co/MCwTCML  based on this code i need to abort current fileupload.

your code works perfectly but  `fileuploadsend` will be triggered initially once without containing backend result.   so i want  `fileuploadsend` block abort code to be shifted somewhere, still abort should work.

Comment: Thank you, that's understood now. I've updated my answer so that a function named `abortUpload` can be called at an arbitrary time to abort the currently uploading file in the sequence :)

Comment: great that you have understood, but as mentioned in question i want to abort it silently without ui.  please see **Note** of Question.

Comment: Ok - I've removed the button.

Comment: you have showed the solution for both the problem, thanks for it.